# confusion in read/write text file in c

Tags: c

I am trying to do some simple read/write in a .txt file. I write a function for reading the content, and another for write back the content-1.

For example, the content in the "counter.txt" is 20. After doing my code, I suppose the console output should show like:

index now is:20

index now is:19

But that shows 20 and 0, I don't understand why. Thanks for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_data() {
    FILE *fptr;
    char *s;
    fptr = fopen("counter.txt","r");
    if (!fptr) {
        printf("fail to open..\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets(s,25,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);

    return atoi(s);
}

void write_data(char *s) {
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("counter.txt","w");
    if (!fptr) {
        printf("fail to open..\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fputs(s,fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
}

int main(void) {
    char index_str[5];
    int index = read_data();
    printf("index now is:%d\n", index);
    sprintf(index_str,"%d",index-1);
    write_data(index_str);

    index = read_data();
    printf("index now is:%d\n", index);
    sprintf(index_str,"%d",index-1);
    write_data(index_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look in read_data(). Where is the storage for the upto 25 characters read by fgets()? s is a pointer. What does it point to?

Comment: in read_data `char *s` points to anywhere or nothing

Comment: so..after the first read_data(), s points to the end of the string..?

Comment: @KennyYang: No, your `s` pointer in `read_data` is never set to point to anything. This gives what the C standard calls "undefined behaviour", and anything can happen.

Comment: Um no. [What in its description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) makes you think so? `s` points to 'nothing' – it has no defined value.

Comment: ok, I have fixed this problem by petting the s pointer in main. But I am still confused that why it points to nothing if I call the function again, which will define the s pointer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `read_data()`, replace

```
char *s;
```

with

```
char s[200];
```

and you will have a valid `s`.  This allocates 200 bytes on the stack, and you (`fgets()`) can safely write something there and use it.

Comment: I think that char s[25] would be more appropriate because that will match the fgets(,25,) he has. Also, KennyYang may consider defining something like #define BUFFER_LEN 25 and use BUFFER_LEN in s[] declaration as well as in fgets (..).

Comment: I agree.  That `#define` is the best approach.

Comment: IMHO: `char s[200]; ...  fgets(s,sizeof s, fptr)` is even better.

Comment: Uh! chux, that is also a very neat solution!